# Creating a class module that stores and displays objects from another class

Tags: python

I am trying to make a class called `Zoo.py`. I have made another class program called `Animal.py` which displays the information that needs to be printed on another program called `Zookeeper`. I have no problem with the `Zookeeper` program.

My problem is that I do not know how to make the `Zoo` class program that has an attribute called `__animals` which will be a list used to store `Animal` objects.  Then I will use the `__init__` method to create an empty list for `__animals`. 
I will create an `add_animal` method that will receive an `Animal` object and append it to the `__animals` list.

Then I will make a `show_animals` method that will print information about each of the `Animal` objects within `__animals` and, if no `Animal`s have been added to the list, it should print out a message saying that there are no `Animal`s.

Here is my `Animals.py` program that the `Zoo` program needs to get information from:

```
# This program defines the Animal class

import random

class Animal:
    # Define what happens when a new animal object is created
    def __init__(self, animal_type, animal_name):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.__name = animal_name
        self.__mood = "happy"

    # Return the animal's type
    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    # Return the animal's name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    # Determine and return the animal's mood
    def check_mood(self):
        # Pick a number between 1 and 3
        random_number = random.randint(1, 3)

        # Set the animal's mood based on the random number
        if random_number == 1:
            self.__mood = "happy"
        elif random_number == 2:
            self.__mood = "hungry"           
        elif random_number == 3:
            self.__mood = "sleepy"

        # Finally, return the mood
        return self.__mood
```

For the `Zoo` class program so far this is all I have:

```
import Animals

class Zoo:
    __animals = []

    # Use method to create an empty list for __animals
    def __init__(self):
        self.__animals = animal_list

    # Receive an Animal object and append it to the __animals list
    def add_animal(self):
        animal.append(animal_list)


    # Determine and return the animal's mood
    def show_animals(self):
        return animal_list
```

I do not need any help for the `ZooKeeper.py` but here is what the program will look like once `Zoo.py` works:

```
Zoo Options
-----------
1.  Add Animal
2.  Show    Animals
3.  Exit
What    would   you like    to  do? 1
What    type    of  animal  would   you like    to  create? Platypus
What    is  the animal's    name?   Penelope

Zoo Options
-----------
1.  Add Animal
2.  Show    Animals
3.  Exit
What    would   you like    to  do? 2

Animal  List
-----------
Penelope    the Platypus    is  sleepy
```

Comment: What exactly is `animal_list` supposed to be?  Did you forget to put a parameter in the `Zoo.__init__()` method?

Comment: animal_list is supposed to be a list that contains the Animal Objects. I don't really know how to do that to make the animal list get information from the Animal Class

Comment: You don't have a problem. I think you think that Python needs to know about the type of your object before you can use it anywhere ... well, it doesn't. After `import Animals` you can create a list of Animals: `[Animal('platypus', 'Irene'), Animal('t-rex', 'ruffles')]` and pass it around in your code.

Comment: Also: `check_mood(self)` should be two-liner: `self.__mood = random.choice(["happy", "hungry", "sleepy"]); return self.__mood`

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you want to add an `animal` object to the zoo, you need to pass the object as a parameter to the `add_animal` method.

As an example:

```
class Zoo:

    def add_animal(self, animal):
        self.__animals.append(animal)
```